# Resx resource files updating without recycling app pool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resx

we heavily rely on resx files for content and translations which work well. However we would like to enable changing content without users losing their sessions by having the app pool recycled. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better approach in which we can still use the resx files.

Cheers

Comment: Use a database instead?

Comment: Thanks. Any alternative ideas? Given the size of the application and amount of content it would be a very big and time consuming process to convert everything over to using a database.

Comment: I guess you could just parse a text file or something, it wouldn't be as easy as using the resx file to access the values though I don't think.  That's the problem when you go down the wrong route, you end up in too deep with a lot of changes to make :(

Comment: Cheers Coulton - yeah I went down the microsoft recommended route!!

Comment: I voted up anyway, hopefully someone can come to your rescue. :P